# How to calculate monthly savers interest profit

Tags: bank-account, interest-rate, savings-account

I am intrigued to understand how the monthly saver accounts work. For instance, I have seen one where you have to put maximum 400 pounds a month for a period of 12 months and there is an interest of 1.5% (Lloyds bank). For an X amount or the maximum of 400 pounds, what would the profit be after the interest applying? Is the calculation below correct?

```
(400*0.00125)+(400*0.00125)*2+(400*0.00125)*3+(400*0.00125)*4+(400*0.00125)*5+(400*0.00125)*6+(400*0.00125)*7+(400*0.00125)*8+(400*0.00125)*9+(400*0.00125)*10+(400*0.00125)*11+(400*0.00125)*12
```

where **0.00125** is `1.5% / 12`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the interest *compounds*, meaning that it is calculated on the *total* value, not just the amount that you put in. If that's the case, then the formula would be:

```
400 * (1 + 0.00125)    +
400 * (1 + 0.00125)^2  +
400 * (1 + 0.00125)^3  +
400 * (1 + 0.00125)^4  +
400 * (1 + 0.00125)^5  +
400 * (1 + 0.00125)^6  +
400 * (1 + 0.00125)^7  +
400 * (1 + 0.00125)^8  +
400 * (1 + 0.00125)^9  +
400 * (1 + 0.00125)^10 +
400 * (1 + 0.00125)^11 +
400 * (1 + 0.00125)^12
```

For example, the last term reflects the growth of the first 400 pounds, since it would compound 12 times:

```
400 * (1 + 0.00125) * (1 + 0.00125) * ...
```

To find the profit, you would subtract out the total contributions:

```
- 400 * 12
```

You *could* subtract out the contribution from each term, but arithmetically they would be the same.

If you want to verify the calculation, the [Monthly Savings Calculator](https://moneyfacts.co.uk/savings-accounts/monthly-savings-calculator/) gives an ending account balance of `4,839.18`, for a profit of `39.18`

Comment: My calculation and yours with the "^" return the same result. Is that just a coincidence or do I need to rest because I am not seeing something obvious? :P

Comment: Your calculations yields 39.00 instead of 39.18. The difference is not large with only 1.5% annual interest but can be significant with higher interest rates and longer periods. For example, with 15% interest the difference in profit would be 408.45 vs 390.

Comment: It would be great if you could find a link that explains the logic behind your calculation. I am trying to understand why it is using power/caret.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Periodic_compounding

Comment: The concept is: If I start with $100 and earn 5% one period, my new balance is 105 (`100 * 1.05`). If I earn another 5%, my new balance is 110.25 (`105*1.05 = 100*1.05*1.05`). So the interest "compounds" by multiplying by the interest factor multiple times.